# Outputting result of PHP function to specific HTML location with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, single-page-application

I have this in my `index.php`:

```
<?php
require_once '/myFunctions.php';

output_layoutHead();
output_layoutHeader();
output_layoutHome();
output_layoutFooter();
```

These 4 functions basically generate my HTML, which looks similar to this:

```
<head>
    //Metatags, title, CSS links, etc.
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="//call JS function">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="//call JS function">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="//call JS function">Help</a></li>                    
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="contentContainer">
        <div id="content">
            Homepage content
        </div>
    </div>

    //JS script links, etc.
</body>
```

Function `output_layoutHome()` generates the entirety of `#contentContainer`. I also have functions for other pages called `output_layoutContact()` and `output_layoutHelp()`.

I basically want the content generated by the `output_layoutHome()` to disappear completely when Contact or Help button is clicked and instead the other function like `output_layoutContact()` or `output_layoutHelp()` to output content in it's place.

I realize I can remove entirety of `#contentContainer` with `$("#contentContainer").remove();` but I'm not sure how to output the result of an another function in it's place.

Can I get some pointers?

Comment: This is not valid: `output_layoutHeader();();`

Comment: @ChrisG Just a typo, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a second file beside index.php and name it contact.php something like that:

```
<?php
require_once '/myFunctions.php';
output_layoutContact();
```

and then add an onclick handler to the contact button with something like that:

```
$( "#content" ).remove();
$( "#contentContainer" ).load( "contact.php" );
```

you could also specify the layout identifier as data in load-call and then conditionally output all content by index.php.